# How to Limit user to enter specific number range like (300-470)

Tags: c#, validation, textbox

I'm working on a project where i have a text box i want to limit user to enter a specific range Like (300-470) in a text box here is my code which works if user enter number greater than 470 it gives error using error provider while if user input number less than 300 then it not give error. Need your Help to figure out the issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Here is my code

```
if(OutputFrequencyTextbox.Text !="" && ConvertToInt(OutputFrequencyTextbox.Text)>=300 && ConvertToInt(OutputFrequencyTextbox.Text)<=470 ) 
{
}
Else if (OutputFrequencyTextbox.Text.Length >=3))
{ OutputFrequencyTextbox.Text ="";
errorprovider(OutputFrequencyTextbox,"Range (300-470)"));
}
else
{
errorprovider.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Well, what type of application is this? I mean windows, web or wpf

Comment: 1st `Else` should be `else`. and why do you dispose errorprovider? is it one time validation?

Comment: # un-lucky its windows form application

Comment: #A.Akram i dispose error provider to remove error provider icon when user input numbers within range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not using Windows Forms at all but there is the [RangeAttribute-Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) (example from MSDN):

```
public class ProductMetaData
{

    [Range(10, 1000, 
        ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}.")]
    public object Weight;

    [Range(300, 3000)]
    public object ListPrice;

    [Range(typeof(DateTime), "1/2/2004", "3/4/2004",
        ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}")]
    public object SellEndDate;

}
```

A specialization of this is the [StringLengthAttribute](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwj9jJDmzsHUAhVIZFAKHWpdCa8QFggwMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute(v%3Dvs.90).aspx&usg=AFQjCNENgq0pQ8_4tutBw8xVhz166E7_wQ&cad=rja) (example from MSDN):

```
public class ProductMetadata
{

    [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
    [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage= "The file name cannot exceed 10 characters long")]
    public object ProductNumber;
}
```

I hope you can figure out how to use that in Windows Forms

Answer (score 1):

You can skip those values(300-470) from committing in TextBox in TextChanged event of the TextBox itself like below,

```
textBox.TextChanged += TextChanged_Event;

private void TextChanged_Event(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(Convert.ToInt32(e.Text) >= 300 && Convert.ToInt32(e.Text) <= 470)
    {
        e.Text = string.Empty;
        (or)
        //Do your logics here like perform validation operation
    }
}
```

Comment: where i have to write this line of code?
textBox.TextChanged += TextChanged_Event;

Comment: i not using Xaml ,
I'm working on windows form application

Comment: Ok. Add the code in the file where you have actually initialized TextBox.

Comment: For Winforms: it has a `EventArgs e` and not a `TextChangedEventArgs e`. But you will not need it: instead of `e.Text`, cast a `((Textbox)sender).Text`.